# How to make JFrame Animation?

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe

I want to know if there's any library or something else that animates JFrames like the BUZZ! animation in yahoo messenger, if there's no existing libraries that do that, so what are the possible algorithms for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own Buzz method for the frame you working upon. Look at the code given below.

**EDIT**
As Suggested by MadProgrammer and DavidKroukamp I have changed the Code to meet the standards. :)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class BuzzFrame extends JFrame 
{
    private JButton buzz = new JButton("BUZZ ME!!");
    public BuzzFrame ()
    {
        super("BUZZ Frame!!");
    }
    public void prepareGUI()
    {
        buzz.addActionListener(new BuzzActionListener(this));
        setSize(300,200);
        getContentPane().add(buzz,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                BuzzFrame bFrame = new BuzzFrame();
                bFrame.prepareGUI();
                bFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
class BuzzActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private Point currLocation;
    private int iDisplaceXBy = 5;
    private int iDisplaceYBy = -10;
    public BuzzActionListener(JFrame frame)
    {
        this.frame = frame;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        currLocation = frame.getLocationOnScreen();
        fireBuzzAction();
    }
    private void fireBuzzAction()
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Point position1 = new Point( currLocation.x + iDisplaceXBy , currLocation.y + iDisplaceYBy );
                Point position2 = new Point( currLocation.x - iDisplaceXBy , currLocation.y - iDisplaceYBy );
                for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
                {
                    frame.setLocation(position1);
                    frame.setLocation(position2);
                }
                frame.setLocation(currLocation);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: (@DavidKroukamp I would make him fix those "bad ideas" before giving an up-vote...but I'm an cynical old bastard;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer very true.... (not the cynical part haha :P) I was contemplating it.... Vishal K, please would you correct the code so I can up vote it again... I only now also see that `Thread.sleep`... and mixed with other bad practices problems are eminent.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I have corrected the code . I hope this time you wont keep contemplating it ;) ..

Comment: @MadProgrammer I appreciate your love and likeness for clean and correct code , and pardon me for that cynical part....;)

Comment: No need for the `invokeXXX` block within `ActionListener` as it should be run already on EDT because actionListener was created and called from EDT, but +1 for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at

- [Timing Framework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework)
- [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)
- [Tween Universal Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

You will need to assess each to determine which best meets your needs

Answer (score 0):

i did this with a simple function:

```js
public void ZUMBIDO() {
        toFront();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            int milisegundos = 50;
            int posiciones = 20;

            public void arriba() {

                Point pos = getLocation();
                pos.translate(0, posiciones);
                setLocation(pos);

            }

            public void abajo() {
                Point pos = getLocation();
                pos.translate(0, -posiciones);
                setLocation(pos);
            }

            public void derecha() {
                Point pos = getLocation();
                pos.translate(posiciones, 0);
                setLocation(pos);
            }

            public void izquierda() {
                Point pos = getLocation();
                pos.translate(-posiciones, 0);
                setLocation(pos);
            }

            public void proceso() {
                try {
                    arriba();
                    Thread.sleep(milisegundos);
                    derecha();
                    Thread.sleep(milisegundos);
                    abajo();
                    Thread.sleep(milisegundos);
                    izquierda();
                    Thread.sleep(milisegundos);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    proceso();
                }

            }

        }).start();

    }
```

YOU can watch it in action with the next code, its a simple chat with echo concept.

https://github.com/MikeSoft/Sistemas_Operativos_Clase/blob/master/chat/src/sistemas/operativos/cliente.java